# More efficient way to do SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, performance, web

I've been using the below php and sql for loading schedule information and real time information for passenger trains in the UK. Essentially you have to find the relevant schedules, and then load the realtime information for each schedule which is in a different table relating to todays trains.

The query is taking a little longer than is really idea and using lots of CPU% which again isn''t ideal. I'm pretty weak when it comes to sql programming so any pointers as to what is inefficient would be great.

This is for an android app and so i've tried to all with one call over http. The prints(*) and > is for splitting the string at the other end.

Here is the code:

```
<?

//Connect to the database
 mysql_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX")
or die ("No connection could be made to the OpenRail Database");
mysql_select_db("autotrain");
//Set todays date from system and get HTTP parameters for the station,time to find trains         and todays locations table.
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$test = $_GET['station'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
$table = $_GET['table'];

//Find the tiploc associated with the station being searched.
$tiplocQuery = "SELECT tiploc_code FROM allstations WHERE c LIKE '$test';";
$tiplocResult =mysql_query($tiplocQuery);
$tiplocRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($tiplocResult);

$tiploc=$tiplocRow['tiploc_code'];
//Now find the timetabled trains for the station where there exists no departure     information. Goes back two hours to account for any late running.
$timeTableQuery = "SELECT tiplocs.tps_description AS 'C',     locations$table.public_departure, locations$table.id,schedules.stp_indicator
,schedules.train_uid
FROM locations$table, tiplocs, schedules_cache, schedules,activations
WHERE locations$table.id = schedules_cache.id
AND schedules_cache.id = schedules.id
AND schedules.id =activations.id
AND '$date'
BETWEEN schedules.date_from
AND schedules.date_to
AND locations$table.tiploc_code = '$tiploc'
AND locations$table.real_departure LIKE '0'
AND locations$table.public_departure NOT LIKE '0'
AND locations$table.public_departure >='$time'-300
AND locations$table.public_departure <='$time'+300
AND schedules.runs_th LIKE '1'
AND schedules_cache.destination = tiplocs.tiploc
ORDER BY locations$table.public_departure ASC
LIMIT 0,30;";

$timeTableResult=mysql_query($timeTableQuery);


while($timeTablerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($timeTableResult)){
$output[] = $timeTablerow;

}

//Now for each id returned in the timetable, get the locations and departure times so the app may calculate expected arrival times.
foreach ($output as $value) {
$id = $value['id'];
$realTimeQuery ="SELECT     locations$table.id,locations$table.location_order,locations$table.arrival,locations$table.public_arrival,
locations$table.real_arrival,locations$table.pass,locations$table.departure,locations$   table.public_departure,locations$table.real_departure,locations$table.location_cancelled,
tiplocs.tps_description FROM locations$table,tiplocs WHERE id =$id AND     locations$table.tiploc_code=tiplocs.tiploc;";

$realTimeResult =mysql_query($realTimeQuery);
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($realTimeResult)){
    $output3[] = $row3;
}
print json_encode($output3);
print("*");
unset($output3);
unset($id);
}


print('>');
print json_encode($output);

?>
```

Many Thanks
Matt

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Oh right ok, thanks for the link. I'll change the way I do it. Still its the sql thats problem and causing the slow down any guidance there would be met with many thanks.

Comment: @Matt: first work out how you're going to change your code-base (to use PDO or MySQLi), implement that change and then come back to us with specific question(s) to do with that code. This really isn't the place for speculative general advice or guidance.

Comment: More worrying (but related) is the direct interpolation of user input like GET variables. Whether you're using mysql, mysqli, or PDO, this is a Bad Thing that creates gaping SQL injection vulnerabilities. Prepared statements as provided by PDO and mysqli are a great way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Not sure it will make things faster, but using a view would certainly make them cleaner. If you run this query often, a stored procedure will both improve performance and help you secure your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue with your setup is this foreach loop because it is unnecessary and results in n number of round trips to the database to execute a query, fetch and analyze the results.

```
foreach ($output as $value) {
```

Rewrite the initial query to include all of the fields you will need to do your later calculations.

Something like this would work.

```
SELECT tl.tps_description AS 'C', lc.public_departure, lc.id, s.stp_indicator, s.train_uid,
lc.id, lc.location_order, lc.arrival, lc.public_arrival, lc.real_arrival, lc.pass, lc.departure, lc.real_departure, lc.location_cancelled
FROM locations$table lc INNER JOIN schedules_cache sc ON lc.id = sc.id
  INNER JOIN schedules s ON s.id = sc.id
  INNER JOIN activations a ON s.id = a.id
  INNER JOIN tiplocs tl ON sc.destination = tl.tiploc
WHERE '$date' BETWEEN schedules.date_from AND schedules.date_to
  AND lc.tiploc_code = '$tiploc'
  AND lc.real_departure LIKE '0'
  AND lc.public_departure NOT LIKE '0'
  AND lc.public_departure >='$time'-300
  AND lc.public_departure <='$time'+300
  AND s.runs_th LIKE '1'
ORDER BY lc.public_departure ASC
LIMIT 0,30;
```

Eliminating n query executions from your page load should dramatically increase response time.

Comment: I want to upvote for a helpful answer, but want to downvote for perpetuating the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: edit the answer to eliminate the sql injection vulnerability (I'm not a php developer)

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed.

First, you are joining tables in the where clause, like this

```
from table1, table2
where table1.something - table2.something
```

Joining in the from clause is faster

```
from table1 join table2 on table1.something - table2.something
```

Next, I'm not a php programmer, but it looks like you are running similar queries inside a loop.  If that's true, look for a way to run just one query.

**Edit starts here**

This is in response to gazarsgo's that I back up by claim about joins in the where clause being faster.  He is right, I was wrong.  This is what I did.  The programming language is ColdFusion:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
<cfscript>
fromtimes = ArrayNew(1);
wheretimes = ArrayNew(1);
</cfscript>

<cfloop from="1" to="1000" index="idx">
<cfquery datasource="burns" name="fromclause" result="fromresult">
select count(distinct hscnumber)
from burns_patient p join burns_case c on p.patientid = c.patientid
</cfquery>
<cfset ArrayAppend(fromtimes, fromresult.executiontime)>

<cfquery datasource="burns" name="whereclause" result="whereresult">
select count(distinct hscnumber)
from burns_patient p, burns_case c 
where p.patientid = c.patientid
</cfquery>
<cfset ArrayAppend(wheretimes, whereresult.executiontime)>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#ArrayAvg(fromtimes)#" metainfo="no" label="from">
 <cfdump var="#ArrayAvg(wheretimes)#" metainfo="no" label="where">
```

I did ran it 5 times.  The results, in milliseconds, follow.

```
 9.563 9.611
 9.498 9.584 
 9.625 9.548 
 9.831 9.769 
 9.792 9.813
```

The first number represents joining in the from clause, the second joining in the where clause.  The first number is lower only 60% of the time.  Had it been lower 100% percent of the time, it would have shown that joining in the from clause is faster, but that' not the case.

Comment: please provide proof of statements like "joining in the from clause is faster"

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the problems with the code, in order to speed up your query, use the EXPLAIN command to evaluate where you need to add indexes to your query.

At a guess, you probably will want to create an index on whatever `locations$table.public_departure` evaluates to.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html